# Settings bundle - New items not showing up in Xcode

Tags: iphone, settings, xcode4.3, bundle

I am a newbie to iOS Development. Learnt a chapter 2 days back about using settings bundle in my apps. The tutorial also showed me how to add new plist files and images into the settings bundle by ctrl+click opening the bundle in Finder.

But the newly added items do not show up in Xcode project organizer list. Is that how it works or do we have an alternative?

[Update at 1:53PM EST by Deepu]
Thank you guys for the replies. Actually I figured out something weird. When I added objects to the settings bundle from Finder, they did not initially show up on Xcode. I closed everything and then reopened Xcode and saw them in the bundle inside Xcode. So I guess the error was on my part expecting the objects to be added in Xcode as soon as I added them to the File system via Finder.

Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the advises.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be there maybe inside any folder. When I add a file I usually add first a group (right click Add group) then there is a new folder so in the folder (example images) I right click and add a file.

Answer (score 0):

It should be there, if not then right click on any folder/file in your xcode, tap on Show or Reveal in Finder, then it will take you to a place where all of your project files are placed, drag and drop from there into your project. It will not automatically pull into your project if you will add them in a folder on your disk. You will have to drag and drop into your project.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Reno Jones